# Can someone please explain this vector space definition to me?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-homomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

Snippet taken from ["Linear Algebra" by Jim Hefferon (4th edition):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTtJE.png)

> **1.2 Definition** Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces of dimensions $n$ and $m$
> with bases $\mathrm{B}$ and $\mathrm{D},$ and that $\mathrm{h}: \mathrm{V} \rightarrow \mathrm{W}$ is a linear map. If
> $$
> \operatorname{Rep}_{\mathrm{D}}\left(\mathrm{h}\left(\vec{\beta}_{1}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> \mathrm{h}_{1,1} \\
> \mathrm{~h}_{2,1} \\
> \vdots \\
> \mathrm{h}_{\mathrm{m}, 1}
> \end{array}\right) \quad \ldots \quad \operatorname{Rep}_{\mathrm{D}}\left(\mathrm{h}\left(\vec{\beta}_{\mathrm{n}}\right)\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> \mathrm{h}_{1, \mathrm{n}} \\
> \mathrm{h}_{2, \mathrm{n}} \\
> \vdots \\
> \mathrm{h}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{n}}
> \end{array}\right)_{\mathrm{D}}
> $$
> then
> $$
> \operatorname{Rep}_{\mathrm{B}, \mathrm{D}}(\mathrm{h})=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
> \mathrm{h}_{1,1} & \mathrm{~h}_{1,2} & \ldots & \mathrm{h}_{1, \mathrm{n}} \\
> \mathrm{h}_{2,1} & \mathrm{~h}_{2,2} & \ldots & \mathrm{h}_{2, \mathrm{n}} \\
> & \vdots \\
> \mathrm{h}_{\mathrm{m}, 1} & \mathrm{~h}_{\mathrm{m}, 2} & \ldots & \mathrm{h}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{n}}
> \end{array}\right)_{\mathrm{B}, \mathrm{D}}
> $$
> is the matrix representation of h with respect to B, D.

Here $h$ is homomorphoism.
What I am not able to understand that if there is a linear mapping, $f:V\to W$, then according to a previous theorem in the same book, the bases of $V$ maps to bases of $W$.
Therefore, if $B$ is the bases of $V$ containing $n$ vectors $\langle B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n\rangle$, then
$\langle h(B_1), h(B_2), \dots, h(B_n)\rangle$ is the bases for $W$.

Now shouldn't in the definition of the attached screenshot $h_ij = 1$; if $i=j$ and $h_ij = 0$; if $i\neq j$? So that the final matrix have to be an identity matrix? What's going on?

<sup>*(The book is available from https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra/ and this definition is on [page 214](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf#page=224). The notation $\mathrm{Rep}_B(\vec v)$ is defined on [page 124](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf#page=134).)*</sup>

Comment: A linear map doesn't always necessarily map a basis to basis!

Comment: Consider the zero map, that takes every vector to $\vec 0$.  That certainly doesn't take bases to bases.

Answer (score 1):

You've not told us how this notation is defined in the book.

I take it that $B=(\beta_1,\dots, \beta_n)$ is an ordered basis of $V$ and $D=(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_m)$ is an ordered basis of $W$.

I think that if you look at the definition of
$\text{Rep}_D (v)$
you will see that the hypothesis is that for each $i$ the vector $h(\beta_i)$ can be written
$$
h(\beta_i)=h_{1,i}\delta_1+\dots +h_{m,i}\delta_m . (*)
$$

If you now look at the definition of $\text{Rep}_{B,D}(f)$ you will see that $(*)$ are exactly the equations you need to make $\text{Rep}_{B,D}(h)$ exactly what the book says.